# Add a var on condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

How can I add the following code in a condition, depending to another div height ?

`var scrollAreaStart = $('.section2').height() - 150;`

I tried this following code but not get it works :

```
function checkHeight() {
    var parentHeight = document.getElementById('mydiv').clientHeight;
    if (parentHeight > 550) {
        var scrollAreaStart = $('.section2').height() - 150;
    } else {
        var scrollAreaStart = $('.section2').height() + 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var scrollAreaStart = $('.section2').height() + (parentHeight > 550 ? -150 : 100);`

Comment: But I don't know what isn't working, so I don't know a good solution for you.

Comment: how can we test your code ?

Comment: Assuming that `parentHeight` returns the correct height, just chuck it inside the `if` conditional. Not sure what more you're asking for here??

Comment: @User-110484 It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
var scrollAreaStart = (parentHeight > 550) ? $('.section2').height() - 150 : $('.section2').height() + 100;
```